# What does this sed command do? And why does it have colons instead of dashes?

Tags: sed

What does this sed command do, and why does it have colons instead of dashes?

```
sed s:[\t]\.:\tNA:g file1_f1.loci  > file1_f1.newloci
```

Comment: sed can use any character as separator for the "s" command. Basically, sed takes whatever follows the "s" as the separator.

Comment: @CarolineDickson, In the original command line, should there be a backslash before the dot, `\.` ?

Comment: What shell/language is that command line meant to be written in? The `fish` shell is the one where it would make most sense (as it does understand `\t` as meaning tab and doesn't have the `[...]` globbing operator), but even there, you'd need to use `\\.` if you wanted `\.` to be passed to  `sed`. `\.` is the same as `.` in that context.

Comment: Apart from having to know what shell is being used, the interpretation of `\t` would depend on the implementation of `sed`. GNU `sed` would interpret it as a tab character, while other implementations would interpret it as a `t`.

Comment: @Kusalananda, in the case of GNU `sed`, that depends on whether `POSIXLY_CORRECT` is in the environment or not. busybox `sed` is one that treats it as TAB unconditionally there (busybox `sed` does honour POSIXLY_CORRECT for the handling of options after non-option arguments, but not for that backslash processing inside bracket  expressions). And of course there's the question of whether the *shell* transforms that `\t` to a TAB first.

Answer (score 2):

Sed doesnt have to use / as a delimiter - it just takes whatever is after the "s" in a search and uses that, so think of the : as / and its a bit easier, this just searches for a tab *followed by anything* and replacing it with a tab and NA. It will read file1_f1.loci and put the changed contents into file1_f1.newloci

Comment: Careful: there is a dot in the pattern string. It searches for a tab plus one other unspecified character (which may even be the next tab). And the g means it does it globally -- every such occurrence in each line is substituted. You could post some sample data, and check the results are what you expect. If the tab is a field separator, and there are empty fields, it will mess up the number of fields every time.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant The dot is escaped and will be escaped when `sed` gets the expression from the shell, so it will actually search for something matching `[\t]` followed by a literal dot.  What `[\t]` matches depends on the `sed` implementation, but it should be "either a backslash or a `t`" if it's POSIX compliant.

Comment: @Kusalananda, as the backslash is not quoted in `\.`, in most  shells (the only exception I'm aware of is `rc`/`akanga`), only `.` will be passed to `sed` as the backslash will have been treated as a quoting operator by the shell (for a character (`.`) which otherwise doesn't need quoting as it's not special to any shell).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas So it is. Thanks. That also means that `[\t]` will be passed as `[t]` to `sed`, matching a `t`.

Comment: @Kusalananda, again depends on the shell. `fish`/`es` will pass a tab (though `es` might expand the glob), `rc`/`akanga` will pass `\t` (and again could expand the glob), most other shells will pass `t`, and all but `fish` will do globbing.

Comment: @Kusalananda The dot was not quoted when I commented. The original post has had it edited four times, and this answer also edited. People who don't quote sed commands at all get what they deserve (which appears to be a magical mystery tour of shells).